# "Cannot access setup.py: No such file or directory" - can't run any .py files?

Tags: python

This problem started while I was installing pyswip and needed to run a setup.py file. Using the command "python setup.py", I'm greeted with the following message: `"python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory."`

I know this question's been asked a lot before, so I've tried everything in previous answers. Including `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python-3.3.0` at the very top of the script and then trying "`chmod +x setup.py`"
gives the following: `"chmod: cannot access` `setup.py': No such file or directory"`.

Trying to run other .py files from the terminal gives the same result.

Running the file in the Python Shell from IDLE doesn't do anything.

Running the "ls -d */" command shows that the Python-3.3.0/ directory, where the .py files in question are, is definitely there.

Am I missing something really obvious? (If it helps, I have Elementary OS 0.2.)

Comment: what about other files? It seems to be not a Python issue - "chmod: cannot access `setup.py': No such file or directory".

Comment: Opening .jpg files in the same way with my photo viewer works fine... it seems to be just .py files :(

Comment: You need to actually be _in_ the directory with the `setup.py` file for the module you're trying to install when you run `python setup.py`. So, if you downloaded a module's source package, you need to unpack that package and cd into the directory it created.

Comment: Anyhow -- given as this is a question about software installation rather than about programming as such (and given that its _answer_ involves an introduction to the `cd` command), it probably belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: has one of the provided answers answered your question? please provide credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 5):

When you run `python setup.py` that requires the `setup.py` file to be in the current directory.

You can control the current directory with the `cd` command.

So:

```
cd /home/acacia/Python-3.3.0/PySwip/pyswip-0.2.3
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge about Elementary OS but you could try to use the full path of the setup.py.

```
python /home/acacia/Python-3.3.0/PySwip/pyswip-0.2.3/setup.py install
```

[EDIT] Can't answer comments, so I just added the install parameter in my answer

Comment: Tried python /home/acacia/Python-3.3.0/PySwip/pyswip-0.2.3/setup.py:
"usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied"

Comment: @user3891313, well, that's not the problem you came here with, so it sounds like a solution to me (just running `cd /home/acacia/Python-3.3.0/PySwip/pyswip-0.2.3` before `python setup.py` would have the same effect). (Yes, you need to run `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop` or some such thing, but that should be in the documentation for the pyswip module).

Comment: If you're getting "usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1", try `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py build` (these are commands usually accepted by setup modules.) You could also try just `setup.py --help`

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the directory that you are going to "setup". For example, if you are installing numpy, and you have git-cloned it, then it probably is located at ~/numpy. So first cd into ~/numpy, and the type the commend like "python setup.py build" there.