# Setting up CPLEX with Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal, cplex

I'm trying to install cplex on Python on my Mac but I'm really stuck.

The `setup.py` file is in the following path:

```
/Users/mac/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/python/2.7/x86-64_osx
```

I am using canopy for running Python.

I entered the following code in Terminal of Mac and the result was as follows:

```
macs-mbp:~ mac$ python setup.py install
/Users/mac/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
macs-mbp:~ mac$
```

I then decided to use `(option --home)` but the result was also terrible:

```
macs-mbp:~ mac$ python setup.py install --home /Users/mac/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex

/Users/mac/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
macs-mbp:~ mac$
```

I tried using `cd` too but that didn't yield an improvement.

Any help would be appreciated for installing cplex on Python on Mac!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it might be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036688/cannot-access-setup-py-no-such-file-or-directory-cant-run-any-py-files) SO question.

What happens if you do the following:

```
cd /Users/mac/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/python/2.7/x86-64_osx
python setup.py install
```

Also, you have to make sure that the "python" above points to the python you want (canopy vs the system python).