# python pip install doesnt work because of several errors (macOS)

Tags: python, pip

I installed python yesterday and experimented a bit with it but when I wanted to install some packages using "pip" it, first of all, wasn't installed and when I installed it using the commands on the python.org page it came with several errors (see below) I tried a lot of things even searching in directory's that turned out where not even there.

As you can see I need some help because I can't do this alone :).

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1z/_9_qzjrd7gn6g4cnxq4w3n180000gq/T/pip-install-YWT87E/aiohttp/


The directory '/Users/NAME/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.


OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-40.0.0-py2.7.egg'
```

Comment: what version of python did you install? and how did you install it?

Comment: I installed the newest python 3.7 from the python.org website.
Although python --version says 2.7.10

Comment: That's going to cause a problem to start.  If you have both installed you might have some environment path issues.  You may also want to use Pip3 rather than Pip dependent upon the version of python you have installed.  I think the simplest way to do so is to simply uninstall all versions of python and then install the newest version of Python by installing Anaconda.  You could then alternatively use Conda to install packages in the anaconda prompt if you are unable to get pip3 working

Comment: is there a easy terminal command to uninstall python or do i need to delete my python directorys?(just to be sure im not doing anything wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo python setup.py egg_info`

Comment: this also gives an error 
    "python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036688/cannot-access-setup-py-no-such-file-or-directory-cant-run-any-py-files